# MacBook (OS X.7) cannot communicate with LCD projector

Tags: macbook, lcd

The computer recognizes the projector, and IDs it in the "displays" menu, but the projector -- both an In-Line and a Hitachi projector -- does not recognize any computer sending input to it.

I have found other users reporting the same problem, but no one reporting a solution.  IS there a solution?  Contrarily, is there a particular make/model of LCD projector that does NOT have this problem?  (I'm frustrated enough to consider buying my own projector for my classroom.)

Comment: Silly question: Are you sending any input to it? (usually fn+f8 or similar)

Comment: As R3TRI8UTI0N says below, please talk to your tech for your school. They are there specifically to support the hardware and software in your school.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the projector is set to the correct input. If there is a remote that came with the projector, try tapping the "Input" button a few times, waiting +5 seconds after each press. Also, I would suggest trying to change the video settings in the projector's settings menu. Such as aspect ratio to, most likely, 16x9 or something to that extent.

Comment: Also, your comment in parenthesis lead me to understand you are teaching in a school? If that is the case you should talk to your Technology Coordinator or Administrator.